# How to hide the console windows in Tor after re-compile

Tags: windows, console, tor

I re-compiled the Tor Browser on Windows with minGW, and after I launch Tor, the console window opens too- he shows me all the details from the begging of launching Tor.
There is a way to hide this console window?

by the way i did the same thing in Linux with Terminal and it did not open the console window.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you can hide the console window is to add to your "main" file this line

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

and re-compile again.

it will open your `tor.exe` console window for less then 1 second, and will close him self automatically.
if any one else knows how to completely avoid the opening of the console window ill be glad to hear the way to do that.